# List of Days in Week Number Excel

Tags: excel, list, days

I have a Date. Ex: 1/1/2017.
I have a week number. Ex: WEEKNUM(1/1/2017) = 1.

How can I list all 7 days, starting from Monday - Ending on Sunday.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is like this:

`=Text(A1,"dddd")`

Or if I understood you correctly, something like this may do the job:

`=(A1*7)+Date(2017,1,1)` to give you the first day in the `a1` week.
You may add `+1` at the end of the formula.

In general, some interesting formulas here:
http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Dates/29795.html

Edit: 
Try this :
`=DATE(Yr,1,1+(Nth-(Dow>=WEEKDAY(DATE(Yr,1,1))))*7)+
Dow-WEEKDAY(DATE(Yr,1,1))`

Taken from here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeWS.htm#NthDoWYear

Comment: Nop it doesn not work. Say, I have Week 19, which should be from Monday 8May to Sunday 14May. It does not give me that.

Answer (score 0):

With week numbers in Row1 (`1` in A1) then in A2 copied down to A8 and A2:A8 across to suit:

```
=DATEVALUE("1/1/17")+7*(A$1-1)+ROW()-1
```